# Optional tuple to tuple of options

Tags: scala

In scala is there an easy way to transform an optional tuple into a tuple of options i.e

```
Option[(Int, Int)] => (Option[Int], Option[Int])
```

Thanks

p.s. now I am just using:

```
val myTuple: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 1))
if (myTuple.isDefined) 
  (Some(myTuple.get._1), Some(myTuple.get._2)) 
else 
  (None, None)
```

Comment: What have you tried? I'm going to answer this anyways but it would be nice if you put down what you tried, first.

Comment: sorry, ive added my current code

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe (not that it is much "easier" than what you have, but more idiomatic):

```
 option.map { case (a,b) => Some(a) -> Some(b) }.getOrElse(None -> None)
```

Comment: It will, however result in a match error if it is not a tuple.

Comment: @Dima yup, just noting that your answer, whole valid, is not a general case answer. Don't worry, I voted it up.  Succinct and clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
val myTuple: Option[(A, B)] = ...
(myTuple.map(_._1), myTuple.map(_._2))
```